mailbox.mbox function in Python is not loading the downloaded mbox email into Python
I am trying to do some analysis with my emails from Gmail. For that, I downloaded my email messages (inbox, span, and thrash folders) from Gmail using Google's takeout option. The download was successful and the downloaded .mbox file was placed on disk. I opened the mbox file and verified that it has a lot of content in it, most of which seem to have been encoded. The size of the mbox downloaded is about 73MB
Now, I am trying to load the contents of the mbox file into an object called "mbox" in python. For that, I wrote the below 3 lines of code
import mailbox

mboxfile='PATH TO DOWNLOADED MBOX FILE'
mbox=mailbox.mbox(mboxfile)
print(mbox)

After running the above 3 lines of code, I got the below output
<mailbox.mbox object at 0x7d882f0eb700>
This made me think that the load was successful
But then to access the keys associated with the mbox file, I wrote the below 3 lines of code
for message in mbox:
    for key in message.keys():
        print(key)

Nothing happens after running this last three lines of code. Expected output is that keys present in the mbox file must be printed. But, that's not happening. This is the problem I'd like to get help with from this community
I suspected that 73 MB is a problem. Other than that I ran the code and seeing no output coming
